# Extract elements given 2D matrix of column indices per row from a 2D matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I tried to resample my data from a block of matrix that defined its indices. Hopefully this example can make it clear:

```
A=rand(18400,100);
A_IDX=randi([1 100],[18400 100]);
```

`A_IDX` consist 18400 rows and 100 columns. I wanted to extract the matrix `A` at the `A_IDX` indices. Result would be something like:

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6];
A_IDX=[1 3; 2 3];
A_Result=[1 3; 5 6];
```

I tried `A(:,A_IDX)` but that gave me 1840x184000 matrix size, which is not what I wanted to do in the first place. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: so `A_IDX` has column indexes per row of `A` then, am I right? I assume you need the same amount of columns always, per row

Comment: yes you're right. Sorry forgot to mention about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could get the linear index equivalent for those indices and then simply indexing into the input array would give us the desired output. Now, to get those linear indices, we would make use of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for the math computations related to the index computations, which would basically involve scaling and offsetting.

**Indexing with 2D array of column indices**

For a `2D` array of column indices, we would have -

```
function out = take_cols(a, col_idx)

n = size(a,1);
lidx = bsxfun(@plus,(col_idx-1)*n,(1:n).');
out = a(lidx);
```

Sample run -

```
>> a
a =
    39    83    39    48    36
    58    74    20    19    50
    69    97    65    34    57
    47    58    80    24    51
>> col_idx
col_idx =
     2     4
     3     5
     1     4
     2     5
>> take_cols(a, col_idx)
ans =
    83    48
    20    50
    69    34
    58    51
```

**Indexing with 2D array of row indices**

For a `2D` array of row indices, it would be -

```
function out = take_rows(a, row_idx)

[m,n] = size(a);
lidx = bsxfun(@plus,row_idx, (0:n-1)*m);
out = a(lidx);
```

Sample run -

```
>> a
a =
    39    83    39    48    36
    58    74    20    19    50
    69    97    65    34    57
    47    58    80    24    51
>> row_idx
row_idx =
     3     2     3     1     2
     4     3     4     2     4
>> take_rows(a, row_idx)
ans =
    69    74    65    48    50
    47    97    80    19    51
```

Comment: Welp, this is considerably better than my mosntrosuity

Comment: Divakar, what if `col_idx` is a logical matrix instead of indices? For example, `a=rand(2,5)`, `b=rand(2,5)`, `c=a>b`, `extracted_a=a(:,c)`. I always get index exceed dimension error everytime. Should I be aware of something here?

Comment: @GregorIsack What's the expected output there? With the mask you are losing out the 2D format and that reduces the masked array, if you do : `a(c)` to a 1D array.

Answer (score 2):

This weird monster of code will give you what you want. It generates proper subscripts for each index and converts them to linear, then just indexes `A` linearly.

```
A_IDX_aux=A_IDX';
reshape(A(sub2ind(size(A),repelem(1:size(A,1),1,size(A_IDX,1)).',A_IDX_aux(:))),[size(A,1), size(A_IDX,2)]).';
```

Comment: Oh wow. I shall split out the code, too confusing for me :p.  I never heard of the `repelem` command. Just curious, Is it better than `repmat`?

Comment: @GregorIsack its different. Repelem repeats each element! its only there in newer versions. However Divakars answer is waaaay better than mine

Comment: Okay got it. I'll look into both! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I find my solution for this task too, but not so fast, as [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707447/4960953) and [Ander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707499/4960953) :)

Behold:

```
res = cell2mat(arrayfun( @(x) A(x,A_IDX(x,:)), (1:size(A,1))', 'UniformOutput',false));
```

It use `cell2mat` and I suppose it is not so fast as `bsxfun`, but hope is still alive and I was curios to test all the 3 solutions. And I got unobvious results!

```
Elapsed time is 0.000058 seconds.   % Divakar
Elapsed time is 0.000077 seconds.   % Andres
Elapsed time is 0.000339 seconds.   % Me
```

This mean `bsxf` is fastest! But using right indexing give fast result too! And my solution was really slow. I suppose it's because of `'UniformOutput', false` - I forced to convert to cells and then back, so it slow my method a lot.

Conclusion:

1. If you can use `bsxf` - use it!
2. Despite the fact that my method looks more visually pleasing than that of Andres, it is still slower.
3. So there is no any sense to post this answer :D I spend some time for current work, maybe it will help someone in future

Comment: Well, the effort is worth some support ;)